# VBA- How to change compare cells to compare rows

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to change the following code to compare entire rows instead of individual cells. I'm a beginner at vba so please explain in simple terms.

```
Sub RunCompare()
    Call compareSheets("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
    End Sub
    Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String, shtAfter As String)
    'Compares sheets by cells and highlight difference
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim mydiffs As Integer
    For Each MyCell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange
        If Not MyCell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(MyCell.Row, MyCell.Column).Value Then
            MyCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtAfter).Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: if you got certain column in a row to compare to decide the "fate" of entire row, you may using `conditional formatting` else just take a look at my answer on how to improve your current code's performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Range` object is a strange beast in Excel and it can take some getting used to its various characteristics.

The phrase

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange`

delivers a `Range` object and when you use the loop

`For Each MyCell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange`

what you are actually doing is implicitly relying on the `Cells` property of the `Range` object to deliver an object that contains all the cells in that range. Excel's help system (in version Office 2010, at least) also indicates this latter object is a `Range` object and I suspect this is a source of confusion amongst beginners, because each of the cells is also a `Range` object in its own right (so the `Cells` property of a `Range` delivers an object which is also a `Range` though different from its parent and which has "elements" each of which is a `Range`)

The loop above is really a shorthand form of

`For Each MyCell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange.Cells`

The `Range` object has many properties, one of which is the `Rows` property. The phrase

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange.Rows`

delivers an object that contains the separate rows of your `UsedRange` and you can then use a loop such as

`For each myRow in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange.Rows`

to look at each row in turn. Here `myRow` is also a Range object. Again, perhaps confusingly, the `Rows` property also delivers a `Range` object which contains "elements", each of which is also a `Range` object.

Unfortunately, you cannot implicitly rely on the `Cells` property with the `myRow` object to loop over the individual cells within each row. So

`For each myCell in myRow`

doesn't work as you'd hope but by explicitly adding the `Cells` property

`For each myCell in myRow.Cells`

does.

**In summary**, you can achieve your row by row comparison by using two loops: the first for the rows (based on the `Rows` property) and a second, nested inside the first, for the cells within a row (based on the `Cells` property).

**As an aside**, you can do much of what you want without using VBA at all. Array formulas in Excel (the ones that require CTL+SHIFT+ENTER when entered from the formula bar) can compare two arrays. For example, the array formula

`{=AND(Sheet1!A1:Z1=Sheet2!A1:Z1)}`

tells whether the range A1:Z1 is the same on two different worksheets and there are other array formulas which can be used to count the number of differences between two ranges.

If you want to highlight the differences between cells in two worksheets use conditional formatting. The trick here is to set the conditional formatting using a formula on the first cell and then to copy this formatting to the other cells. So set the conditional formatting for cell `Sheet2!A1` using the formula

`=Sheet1!A1<>Sheet2!A1`

Make sure that the formula uses relative `A1` rather than absolute `$A$1` cell addresses (editting the formula if necessary) and then `Copy` the format (using `Paste Special Format`) from cell `Sheet2!A1` to the rest of the cells on `Sheet2`.

Comment: It still end up comparing cells. In addition, don't you think that it will be more resource used in comparing? you get the row, and that loop through the cells inside the row to compare, it became follow the big-O notation of N power to 2 . Anyway, the native way you describe here is quite nice for small number of rows to compare, just that need create another worksheet and setup the formula + conditional formatting. Just that what will happen if user got 10k rows of data to compare?

Comment: @Keong, if you've got 10k rows to compare you might have to leave the VBA code running for a while. Same applies if you use native Excel. Have you tested anything on successively larger sized data sets? By definition, two rows are the same if and only if all of their corresponding cells are the same - so the way to compare rows is to compare their corresponding cells and both mechanisms I've outlined do that. Any mechanism for comparing rows would have to take the same approach though in some languages the cell-by-cell comparison might be hidden from view within a native function.

Comment: @DMM .Sorry, but are you able to give me a rough overview of how I may actually code the two loops or perhaps a rough code? I've changed my original code by using the rows property instead of cell property but I'm presented with a mismatch error.

Comment: Nest the `For each myCell in myRow.Cells` loop inside the loop `For each myRow in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange.Rows`. Put the comparison statements inside the innermost loop. Both myCell and myRow should be declared as Range objects via Dim statements, particularly if you are using Option Explicit (and its good practice to do this).  It should all be very similar to your existing code but with an extra loop. Look up nested loops if you need more help or alternatively, edit your question show your updated code and indicate where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to compare row. You can improve your current method.

1. Set `mydiffs` to long type (vba initial value with long, so no need convert to integer) 
2. Add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to enhance the script performance.

```
Sub RunCompare()
    Call compareSheets("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
End Sub
Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String, shtAfter As String)
    'Compares sheets by cells and highlight difference
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim mydiffs As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange
        If Not MyCell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(MyCell.Row, MyCell.Column).Value Then
            MyCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            mydiffs = mydiffs + 1
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtAfter).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a work around to compare rows? Maybe multiple loops across the row or something?

Comment: I did add the comment at your question there

Comment: Sorry, but how do I use conditional formatting? I basically want to do a lookup of an entire row in sheet1 to see if it matches another row in sheet2, then move down to the next row in sheet1 and repeat till all rows are matched in both worksheets.

Comment: Well, I just check that the conditional formatting only can limit to cell. Just forget about it

Comment: oh man...hopefully someone else knows if I can restrict to a row array. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Keong, I disagree with your statement that "there is no way to compare row". See my answer for why I think this is the case, as I believe I've demonstrated two ways of comparing rows: one based on VBA and the other based on native Excel.